# Тире перед частицей Не + уточнение

Tags: пунктуация

Здравствуйте, форумчане! 
Есть предложение:"Создание мыла ручной работы не только очень увлекательное, но и творческое занятие". 
Нужно ли здесь тире перед НЕ? Подлежащее и сказуемое - имя существительное, но есть еще уточнение в предложении...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, тире нужно, потому что случай не относится к данному исключению: 1. Если перед сказуемым, выраженным существительным в именительном падеже, стоит отрицание не, то тире не ставится, например:Бедность не  порок. http://www.rusyaz.ru/pr/ptr.html

Здесь не отрицание, а двойной союз "не только, но и ". Здесь просто просится "это", которому обычно предшествует пауза, заменяемая тире.

Comment: Спасибо Вам за ответ:)

Answer (score 7):

Случаев, когда тире между подлежащим и сказуемым не ставится, несколько.
В этом предложении **тире** ставить **не нужно**, так как между подлежащим и сказуемым стоит составной союз НЕ ТОЛЬКО..., НО И.
Тире не ставится, если "Между подлежащим и сказуемым-существительным стоит вводное слово, обстоятельство или дополнение, а также **союз** или **частица**: Грач, конечно, птица умная и самостоятельная, но голоса у него нет (Паустовский); Москва теперь порт пяти морей; Этот ручей лишь начало реки".[Здесь](http://www.gramota.ru/class/coach/punct/45_172)
Обратите внимание, что интонация тире тоже не требует.

Comment: А Вы попробуйте произнести без паузы :"Создание мыла ручной работы не только очень увлекательное, но и творческое занятие".Розенталь не так категоричен, он пишет:"Тире ОБЫЧНО не ставится", но во многих перечисленных  случаях тире возможно, если надо интонационно подчеркнуть деление предложения на две части либо выделить один из главных членов.
Тире ставится для указания места распадения простого предложения на две словесные группы, что и происходит в данном случае. Перед двойным союзом предложение распадается на 2 группы-тему и рему. Чтобы облегчить его понимание, нужно тире.

Comment: А запятой недостаточно разве?  Зачем дублировать? Считаю тире лишним.

Comment: Ваше право. Видимо, знаки препинания здесь зависят от того, как мы прочитаем предложение, а читаем мы по-разному. Я вот с паузой, Вы - без паузы.

Comment: И я с паузой.

Answer (score 0):

Здесь возможно интонационно-логическое тире.